# What happens when unsaturated primary alcohol is reacted with acidic potassium dichromate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

It is clear that the hydroxy group in the substrate gets oxidised to carboxylic acid. But what happens to the double/triple bond in the unsaturated primary alcohol when it reacts with acidic potassium dichromate?